# How do I find two numbers in an array that are equal to a target number

Tags: javascript, addition

I'm looking to find two numbers in an array that are equal to a particular target number. I thought this would be a simple task using .filter but for some reason my code only works when I'm looking for a target number of 4 but doesn't work for anything else?

What am I missing here?

```
var numbers2 = [1,2,3,4];
var target = 3;
var found = numbers2.filter((num) => {
  return (num + num) !== target;
});
```

console returns `(4) [1,2,3,4]` as opposed to `2[1,2]`.

Comment: So you need to do two loops over the array. Your code just doubles the single index you are looping over.

Comment: @epascarello im not sure im following. If you can, could you demonstrate how you would do that please?

Comment: @PRSHL I understand that completely and totally agree (I also appreciate the website ive been looking for something to train my skills, ive been learning to code for about a month and half now).  To reiterate could any of you further explain what you mean by two loops?

Comment: I am not doing your homework. How would you do it with paper? does 1+2==3 ? yes, Does 1+3 === 3? no, does 1+4 === 3? no, does 2+3 === 3? No, does 2+4 equal 3? no, does 3 + 4, equal 3? no. Figure out how to implement that in two loops. `for(){ for () {} }`

Comment: Realise that with `num + num` you are doing `num * 2`, i.e. you are not combining any *two* numbers, but always pairing a number with itself.

Comment: @trincot thank you, that makes a lot of sense, thank you

Comment: @JohnLord okay, noted! Im going to keep working on this and WHEN I find a solution ill post it here. Thank you again

Comment: what trincot said.  So you can never, ever match a number to 3 since 3 is odd. You need to do a foreach on that array and then in the loop, compare that value, one at a time, to the dataset again, adding them.  Be sure to not compare if the numbers match.

Comment: What do you mean by "only works when I'm looking for a target number of 4"? When your target is 4, you get `[1, 3, 4]` instead of `[1,3]`. Also, should `[2,2]` count, or should it not (as the '2' only appears once in the array)?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var numbers = [1,4,3,2,6,8,12,1,1,1,2,3,4];
    var target = 3;
    var output = [];
    
    // Use a set to remove duplicate numbers
    numbers = [...new Set(numbers)];  // Only do this step if you dont want duplicates ( like 2+2 = 4 so if your target was for 2, would not show up in the list )

    // Sort the numbers from lowest to highest
    numbers.sort( (a,b) =>a-b);
    
    // Get index of first number that matches the target or is greater than the target
    let index;
    for( let i =0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if( numbers[i] >= target ) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // Remove all numbers from the array starting at the previous index as these are not possible to add up with another number to the target
    if( index ) {
      numbers.splice(index, numbers.length - index );
    }

 // Loop through the remianing array to get first number
    numbers.forEach( ( num1, index1) => {
      // Loop through array again to get second number
      numbers.forEach( (num2, index2) => {
        // Check if number is same is same index as you dont want to add the same value to itself, then check if the 2 numbers equal the target number
        if( index1 !== index2 && num1 + num2 === target ) {
          // If number already exists in array dont duplicate otherwise add it to the array
          if( output.indexOf( num1 ) == -1 ) {
            output.push( num1);
          }
          // If number already exists in array dont duplicate otherwise add it to the array
          if( output.indexOf( num2 ) == -1 ) {
            output.push( num2);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    console.log( output);
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it might be difficult to see why. Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of your code.

Comment: added comments to explain

Comment: `.foreach()` iterates over the entire array. Ordering the data and applying some simple optimisations can eliminate over half the required searching. It may not matter for an array of four numbers, but for an array of 100 numbers this will be enormously wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

It makes very little sense to get an array of single numbers, because you'll get all the numbers except for the last one unless the array starts at zero or there are numbers skipped. So I've written a function that'll return an array of single numbers or an array of expressions (strings).

First, make a copy of the array:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const copy = array.slice(0);
```

Next, use `.flatMap()` for the first set of iterations:

```
array.flatMap(num => { // This is the outer loop of numbers
```

If the third parameter `expression` is `undefined` it will default to `false`. Then `.filter()` the `copy` array, the criteria being that the number from the outer loop plus the current number of the inner loop equals the target number AND the numbers cannot be identical.

```
copy.filter(n => n !== num && target === n + num);
/*
Iterations on the first iteration of outer loop
1 + 1, 1 + 2, 1 + 3,...
*/
```

If `expression` is `true`, then use `.flatMap()` to return an expression (string) of whatever equals the target number or an empty array (which returns as nothing since `.flatMap()` flattens it's returns by a level). If both numbers are identical an empty array will be returned.

```
copy.flatMap(n => n === num ? [] : 
  target === n + num ? `${n} + ${num}` : 
  []
);
```

If `expression` is `true` half of the array is returned so that there isn't any reversed dupes (ex. 6+2 and 2+6)

```
let half = result.length / 2;
result = result.slice(0, half);
```

```js
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
// [1, 2, 3,...10]
const array10 = [...new Array(10)].map((_, i) => i + 1);
// [0, 2, 4, 6,...18]
const arrayEven = [...new Array(10)].map((_, i) => i * 2);

function operands(array, target, expression = false) {
  const copy = array.slice(0);
  let result = array.flatMap(num => {
    if (expression) {
      return copy.flatMap((n, i) => 
        num === n ? [] : 
        target === n + num ? `${n} + ${num}` : 
        []
      );
    }
    return copy.filter(n => n !== num && target === n + num);
  });
  if (expression) {
    let half = result.length / 2;
    result = result.slice(0, half);
  }
  return result;
}

// Return as an array of single numbers
log(array10);
log('3: '+operands(array10, 3));
log('8: '+operands(array10, 8));
log('5: '+operands(array10, 5));
log(arrayEven);
log('2: '+operands(arrayEven, 2));
log('8: '+operands(arrayEven, 8));
log('15: '+operands(arrayEven, 15));
log('=======================');
// Return as an array of expressions (string)
log(array10);
log('3: '+operands(array10, 3, true));
log('8: '+operands(array10, 8, true));
log('5: '+operands(array10, 5, true));
log(arrayEven);
log('2: '+operands(arrayEven, 2, true));
log('8: '+operands(arrayEven, 8, true));
log('15: '+operands(arrayEven, 15, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the array location of your target number through using a array.forEach, array.indexOf(), array.find(), and array.findIndex():

```
let numbers2 = [1,2,3,4];
let target = 4;

//Using foreach
numbers2.forEach((item, index)=>{
if (item == target){
  console.log("Found the target at array location "+index);
}
});

//Or through using indexOf():
console.log("Found the target at array location "+numbers2.indexOf(target));

//Or through using find():
const found = numbers2.find(element => element == target);
console.log("Found "+target+" in the array.");

//Or through findIndex():
const target1 = (a) => a == target;
console.log("Found the target at array location "+numbers2.findIndex(target1));
```

Comment: Whilst it's not immediately obvious in the question, the OP is not looking for one number, but two numbers that, when added, total to the value of the target number. e.g. If the target is 3, he'd be looking for 1 & 2. FWIW, what you suggest here can be done more efficiently with `.indexOf()`

Comment: That is true, answer updated.

Comment: What you're trying to answer is more like `numbers[something] === 4`, the OP's question is more like `numbers[one_thing] + numbers[another_thing] === 4 `

Comment: You are right, thanks for explaining. However, I'll leave this answer up because some of these functions might be relevant in achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- you only need one pair
- [2,2] does not count when your target is 4 (as '2' only appears once in the array)

One way to go is:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let target = 4;
let output = [];
const N = numbers.length
outer: for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] === target) {
            output.push(numbers[i], numbers[j])
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
console.log(output); //[1,3]
```

---

**Edit:** even if you want more than one pair, it's easy to modify to get that effect (now the target is 5):

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let target = 5;
let output = [];
const N = numbers.length
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] === target) {
            output.push([numbers[i], numbers[j]]) 
        }
    }
}
console.log(output); //[[1,4], [2,3]]
```

Comment: Suppose the target was 5. The result should then give two pairs.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the OP did not mention that. It's comparable to how `find` and `filter` have different behaviors. That said, it's easy to modify to allow multiple pairs. I'll edit it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal case for the humble `for` loop. Methods like `.forEach()` will always try to loop over all the elements in an array, but if we order the data before we start the search we can break early and eliminate a lot of searching.

Ergo...

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
var target = 5;
var output = [];

// Handling ordered data is much faster than random data so we'll do this first
numbers.sort();
// We want to start the inner search part way up the array, and we also want
// the option to break so use conventional for loops.

for (let i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  for (let j=i+1; j<numbers.length;j++) {
    // If the total = target, store the numbers and break the inner loop since later numbers
    // will all be too large
    if ((numbers[i]+numbers[j])===target) {
        output.push([numbers[i], numbers[j]]);
      break;
    }
  }
  // Stop searching the first loop once we reach halfway, since any subsequent result
  // will already have been found.
    if (numbers[i]>(target/2)) {
    break;
  }
}

console.log( output);
```